# Local NPM/Atmosphere package repositories for Meteor applications without internet access

Tags: meteor, npm, atmosphere

I'm currently working on a fork of the Meteor application **[Rocket Chat](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat)**. I have a requirement to stand up the application for testing and development on an isolated network, so no internet access whatsoever.

I can't just get it running on a connected system and then copy it wholesale into the disconnected lab. Rather, I need to be able to check out a copy of the source code (from a local SCM) and then run Meteor, letting it perform all necessary compilation and dependency resolution on the fly.

Even though it is a huge kludge, I was hoping that I could just copy the **.meteor** folder from a working system directly onto the target system so that it would already have a cache of all required packages and therefore not need to reach out to any repositories. However, from what I have found, that only works for Meteor dependencies downloaded from Atmosphere.

Within Rocket Chat, there are several private packages (such as **rocketchat-ldap**) that have dependencies on NPM packages (in this case, **ldapjs**). When the application is run and these packages are built, the **.npm** folder in the user's home directory gets populated with those NPM packages. So, I tried to package that folder up along with the **.meteor** folder to accomplish the same task.

Unfortunately, when I tested it on the offline system, despite having the populated **.npm** folder, Meteor spits out the following error:

> While building package rocketchat:ldap:
>   error: Can't install npm dependencies. Are you connected to the internet?

Obviously, I'm not connected - by design.

So, I am currently looking into **[Sinopia](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia)** to stand up an NPM repository mirror on our local network that can host these dependencies. However, I have no idea how I'm supposed to point Meteor to the alternate server. The Meteor documentation includes information about the **Npm.depends** and **Npm.requires** directives, which the application uses, but I can't find anything about specifying a URL from which to find said packages.

Further, is it possible to do something similar with the Atmosphere packages? Or is copying the **.meteor** folder the only way? As in, is there some application out there that I can use to host some of the Meteor packages? Or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: What about `meteor build`? Is that an option for you? Since you won't be able to do any serious development on that offline machine anyways, it probably doesn't make sense to deploy anything but the bundle. I believe it will be easier (trivial?) to get the bundle to run offline.

Comment: That may just be the only way to go, but I was hoping it wasn't. It's frustrating that having internet access is required to run the application otherwise.

Comment: I guess I don't see what's wrong with running the bundle created by `build`. Running `meteor` directly is meant for development, and I can't see why you would like to develop on a machine without internet.

Comment: Just unique (government) requirements in which some lab activities have to occur and stay there.

Comment: well, I guess you could always "spoof" npm and overwrite npmjs.com in your /etc/hosts file to a local server of your choice where you've replicated the packages you require (not saying that latter part would be easy, though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went with, which isn't as elegant as I'd hoped was the following:

First, I copied the `.meteor` folder from the user account of a "working" system (this contains the *Meteor* executable and all of the *Meteor* packages downloaded from *Atmosphere*) to the user account of the disconnected target system. This allowed the target system to run Meteor.

Second, the *NPM* packages in question were being downloaded directly into the private packages in the source, but the `.gitignore` file on the source was set to ignore the `node_modules` folders. So I altered that and then checked those `node_modules` folders into the source with the rest of the application.

So, for example, the application source included a `/packages/rocketchat-ldap/.npm/package` folder. Then, when the application was run using `meteor`, the associated *NPM* packages (such as **ldapjs**) would get downloaded directly into a `node_modules` folder in that folder structure, at which point the private packages could be built.

Now, the source code in Git already contains those downloaded packages, so when a copy is checked out onto the disconnected target system, there is no need to download them.

Fortunately, this did not increase the size of the source very much (just a few hundred kilobytes).

The result is that when running `meteor` to run the application on the target system, all dependencies are already in place, and no internet connection is required.